# Need help figuring out how to have buttons that can delete, edit, or add a new item to a database

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I want to have a php file that can be used to edit, view, delete, and add new products. I have the viewing and adding new products parts done, but what I am trying to do now, is when you view the table that contains the database information have a button for editing, deleting, and adding new items. The code that I want to add to the buttons to is as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
td
{
padding:15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","herp","lerp","derp");

$search=$_POST['search'];
$searchoption=$_POST['searchoption'];

$query= "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE $searchoption = '".$search."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);     
if (!$result) {
printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
exit;
} 
?>
<table>
<th> Information</th>
<?php     
while ($contact = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {



echo "<tr>";
echo "<th> Item Number  </th>";
echo "<th> Item Name  </th>";
echo "<th> Description  </th>";
echo "<th>  Inventory      </th>";
echo "<th> Price      </th>";
echo "<th> Active or Non-Active </th>";
echo "<th> Photo      </th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$contact['item_number']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$contact['item_name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$contact['item_description']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$contact['item_inventory']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$contact['item_price']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$contact['item_active_or_nonactive']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$contact['item_photo']."</td>";
echo "</tr><br/>";
}
?>
</table>
</html>
```

If my question is not specific enough please let me know and I will try and narrow it down, but i am mainly looking for a push in the right direction so i can figure out what to do, because as of right now i am at a loss.

Comment: do you know using $_GET params and using $_POST vars sent after form validation?

Comment: search a ready example of this manipulations (add , edit delete) in php

Comment: Ah no i did not. I am very new to php and html and databases, and my bosses have the approach to these things as trial by fire, so i know next to nothing. I do know that the search works and that is about all haha. However, I am trying to learn and not make mistakes in the future.

Comment: see this [tutorial](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/)  (pagination part are optional)

Comment: i have added my comment as answer on the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search about **php add edit delete**

see this tutorial about [Basic PHP System: View/Edit/Delete/Add Records](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/1969-basic-php-system-vieweditdeleteadd-records/)
 (pagination part are optional)

Comment: One question though, would it work if i had all the different php elements on one page?

Comment: you can put code in different files and in main file just include it and you can add an if else statement on a $_GET['action'] for example (refer to Ben Poulson answer)

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider implementing some type of RESTful server. It makes things a lot simpler.

There are lots of [resources](http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/01/13/introduction-to-writing-a-rest-server-in-php/) to get you started if you decide to go down this route.
Here's a very simple framework for implementing REST in php. http://peej.github.com/tonic/

Answer (score 0):

Woah, first of all you should sort out all the MySQL injection vulnerabilities you have.
Secondly, I would do something like this.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['action'] ) )
{
    switch( $_GET['action'] )
    {
        case "add":
            //Display HTML form for adding new entry
        break;

        case "edit":
            if( isset( $_GET['item_number'] ) )
            {
                //Display HTML form for editing entry
            }
        break;

        case "delete":
            if( isset( $_GET['item_number'] ) )
            {
                //"Are you sure you want to delete $item_number?"
            }
            else
            {
                //Display HTML form for selecting which entry you want to delete
            }
        break;
    default:
        echo "<td><a href=/products.php?action=add'>Add new item</td>";
        $query = 'SELECT ID,Title,Cost FROM tableProducts WHERE CategoryID="'.$id.'" ORDER BY Rank;';
        if (($resource = @mysql_query($query, ...)) === false) {
            while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
                echo "<td>".$row['Title']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['Cost']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=/products.php?action=edit&id='".$row['ID']."'>Edit item?</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=/products.php?action=deete&id='".$row['ID']."'>Delete Item ?</td>";
            }
        }
    break;

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah this is just kind of a learning exercise at the moment, and when i am going to connect it to my server for real i am going to have help sorting through the code and fixing problems or vulnerabilities. And thank you for the code, I will look over it and figure out how to have buttons that tie into those commands

Comment: In the table you're displaying in your code, add extra columns for things like "Edit" or "Delete", and link them to a URL like example.com/yourPage.php?action=edit&itemid=$item_number

Comment: But would that not just make new columns instead of say a checkbox or button?

Comment: It's completely up to you how you structure your pages!

Comment: Haha what i meant was, if i added extra columns could i make buttons or checkboxes in there? What i want to do is have the list of data, and then next to each entry be able to click "edit" "delete". Then at the very bottom have a button for "add new". That is what i was asking help on how to do